# how to print a new line in aws Lambda and python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a list of values I'd like to display. After each value, I'd like for a new line to be printed. This is what I have so far but it's not working

```
scores = [
                {"Result": "Won",
                 "Date": "Today"
                },
                {"Result": "Lost",
                 "Date": "Yesterday"
                },

            ]    

my_str = ""
        for k in range(len(scores)):
            result = scores[k]['Result']
            date = scores[k]['Date']
            my_str += result + " on " + date
            my_str += '\n';

        message = my_str
        statusCode = 200
```

This works fine but there's no new line after each value. Does anyone know how to achieve this in aws lambda

Comment: What do you mean by "print" from Lambda? Are you wanting to show some output in the debug logs? Your code does not include a `print()` statement, nor does it show a full Lambda function, so we don't know what is being done with `message`. Could you please edit your question to show more code and/or explain what you are wanting done with `message`?

Answer (score 0):

Printing the array as JSON will do the trick.